# PDE is symmetric in x and y? What does this mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is meant by 'symmetric in x and y' in the following example?

'Note that the PDE is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ but the solution doesn't appear to be. What happened?'

$ \dfrac{ \partial u }{ \partial x} + \dfrac{ \partial u }{ \partial y } = e^xf(y - x) - e^xf'(y - x) + e^xf'(y - c) = e^xf(y - x) = u$

Thank you.

Comment: Please improve your question. What is your PDE? What is your solution?

Comment: A PDE is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ if you generate the same equation by interchanging $x$ and $y$. You might need to rearrange the terms a bit after the interchange to see this, though.

Comment: @MrYouMath I posted the example they gave. This isn't a problem - i'm simply confused by the terminology used by the example and do not understand its implications.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thanks. What's the difference between what you're specifying and the symmetry of the solution itself? Perhaps, I'm misunderstanding what you're saying. Could you please post an example to illustrate?

Comment: I think you have an example - in fact, that's the point of your exercise! Your PDE (presumably, $\partial u/\partial x + \partial u/\partial y=u$) is easily seen to be symmetric, since changing $x$ and $y$ yields the same thing. Now, any function of the form $u(x,y)=e^xf(y-x)$ is a solution by direct computation but $u(y,x) \neq u(x,y)$. Thus, the solution is not symmetric, even though the PDE is.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Very good. Thank you.